# Reordering columns in CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, pandas

Question has been posted before but the requirements were not properly conveyed. I have a csv file with more than 1000 columns:

```
A   B   C   D ....  X   Y   Z
1   0   0.5 5 ....  1   7   6
2   0   0.6 4 ....  0   7   6
3   0   0.7 3 ....  1   7   6
4   0   0.8 2 ....  0   7   6
```

Here X , Y and Z are the 999, 1000, 10001 column and A, B, C , D are the 1st,2nd,3rd and 4th. I need to reorder the columns in such a way that it gives me the following.

```
D   Y   Z   A   B   C   ....X
5   7   6   1   0   0.5 ....1
4   7   6   2   0   0.6 ....0
3   7   6   3   0   0.7 ....1
2   7   6   4   0   0.8 ....0
```

that is 4th column becomes the 1st, 1000 and 1001th column becomes 2nd and 3rd and the other columns are shifted right accordingly.

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted and why the many [related](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pandas+reorder+columns) questions don't answer your question? This just requires you to reorder the column index and then `reindex` the df by passing the new order

Comment: Use Excel or an open source equivalent

Comment: @EdChum, Yes, but there are thousand columns. How do i reorder a so many columns. Is there a generic way? New to python

Comment: @EdChum, `import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

ncols = df.columns.tolist()

cols = ncols[-1:] + ncols[:-1]

df[cols].to_csv('test1.csv',index=False)`  This code here brings the last column to the first. But i am stuck on how to reorder random columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is how to reorder your columns in a custom way.

For example you have the following DF and you want to reorder your columns in the following way (indices):

5, 3, rest...

DF

```
In [82]: df
Out[82]:
   A  B    C  D  E  F  G
0  1  0  0.5  5  1  7  6
1  2  0  0.6  4  0  7  6
2  3  0  0.7  3  1  7  6
3  4  0  0.8  2  0  7  6
```

columns

```
In [83]: cols = df.columns.tolist()

In [84]: cols
Out[84]: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

reordered:

```
In [88]: cols = [cols.pop(5)] + [cols.pop(3)] + cols

In [89]: cols
Out[89]: ['F', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'G']

In [90]: df[cols]
Out[90]:
   F  D  A  B    C  E  G
0  7  5  1  0  0.5  1  6
1  7  4  2  0  0.6  0  6
2  7  3  3  0  0.7  1  6
3  7  2  4  0  0.8  0  6
```

Comment: @DigantaBharali, did it help?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   A  B    C  D  X  Y  Z
0  1  0  0.5  5  1  7  6
1  2  0  0.6  4  0  7  6
2  3  0  0.7  3  1  7  6
3  4  0  0.8  2  0  7  6

In [5]: df.reindex(columns=['D','Y','Z','A','B','C','X'])
Out[5]:
   D  Y  Z  A  B    C  X
0  5  7  6  1  0  0.5  1
1  4  7  6  2  0  0.6  0
2  3  7  6  3  0  0.7  1
```